PACT contract testing for microservices uses kafka as communication
I am currently working on a project where we have kafka implementation in micro service architecture. Were you successful in creating contract test cases for mS to kafka topic interaction please using pact-jvm ?
My implementation is microservice1 publishes a message to a kafka topic. microservice2 retrieve messages from the Kafka Topic.
